# Parallax Website - fix Background images for Interent Explorer 10 mobile

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, user-agent, parallax

For iPad and other devices I disabled the scrolling of background images, because of performance problems. All works fine.

How can I disable scrolling for IE10 and IE10 mobile (Tablet)?

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional commenting in your HTML file.

If the browser agent is/is not equal to IE10 then include/exclude a CSS File

```
<head>
    <![if !IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nonIE.css" />
    <![endif]>
    [if IE]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css" />
    <![endif]-->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared.css" />
</head>
```

Then within each browser specific css file, you can enable any features as required.

Or use a "display:none;" on an css element, to completely hide it from a browser within your conditional css.

**Note: Conditional comments are an IE-only feature, other browsers treat them as ordinary HTML tags.**

The above snippet borrowed from here: http://codebox.org.uk/pages/articles/conditional-comments and the article goes in to much more detail than I have. It's a good little read.